# Installing misago

Tags: python, django, pip

I want to build a forum using misago but I cannot install it. Everytime I use **pip install misago** i get the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_sg0mt_y\misago\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
README = open(os.path.join(SETUP_DIR, 'README.rst')).read()

File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 716: character maps to <undefined>
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_sg0mt_y\misago\

I searched if they are compatible with python 3.X and they are. I've also installed ez-setup and setuptools to help but to no avail.

I'm using windows 10, python 3.5.

Comment: Have you tried installing in a virtualenv?

Comment: Currently I am using a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checko[image]ut the following required packages needed for `misago` to install, if you have all of them. A screenshot from PC when I install the package. Am suspecting the `unidecode` package is missing.